# nginx error "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

`nginx -t` results in the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:8

Below is the contents of the code in the `/ etc / nginx / sites-available / default` file:

```
server {
        listen 27016;
        server_name 52.79.70.237;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:27016;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name 52.79.70.237;
        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me why the error occurred.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` after the first `location` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart nginx. If you do not want to restart it, you can restart it by killing the process.

```sh
netstat -tnlp
```

The following table appears. Check the number next to the leftmost process name.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1220/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14263/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2495/nginx: master
```

Enter the following command.

```sh
kill -2 2495
```

This will force the process to terminate. Now type nginx again and nginx will run.